# set infowindow while mouseover not in marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, infowindow

I'm new to `google map`. I set `infowindow` for 8 latlong points, while `mouseover` on the marker.

I split my page, 70% for map and 30% for html page.

I set 8 div and 8 markers respectively

Is there anyway to set up `Infowindow`, while mouseover in `respective html div`?

Answer (score 2):

Very easy. If you have a `<div id="html-div">HTML div</div>` you want to associate with a certain `infowindow` and `marker`, then :

```js
document.getElementById('html-div').onmouseover = function() {
   infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
document.getElementById('html-div').onmouseleave = function() {
   infowindow.close();
}
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/6cf0760k/**